# if statement in R. Error argument is of length zero

Tags: r

This is my code

```
for (i in 101:length(temp[,6]))
{ 
  if (   temp[i-1,5]< temp[i,5]  ) 
  print(temp[i,])

}
```

temp is my data

```
     000001.SZ.Open 000001.SZ.High 000001.SZ.Low 000001.SZ.Close 000001.SZ.Volume 000001.SZ.Adjusted
2016-01-01          11.99          11.99         11.99           11.99                0            9.81595
2016-01-04          12.00          12.03         11.23           11.33         67619700            9.27563
2016-01-05          11.27          11.57         11.15           11.40         79592300            9.33293
2016-01-06          11.42          11.56         11.39           11.53         61884700            9.43936
2016-01-07          11.41          11.41         10.91           10.94         20971300            8.95634
2016-01-08          11.21          11.29         10.90           11.12         89703300            9.10370
```

looks like this. I checked the data with code  `is.numeric`

```
is.numeric(temp)
[1] TRUE
```

and `is.null`

```
is.null(temp)
[1] FALSE
```

Therefore all the value in "temp" has meaning and able to calculate.

I got the result

```
Error in if (temp[i - 1, 5] < temp[i, 5]) print(temp[i, ]) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Please tell me where is the problem with this code.

Comment: It seems odd that you set the loop for the length of `temp[,6]` but then operate on `temp[,5]`.    Did you want to make your loop limits be `length(temp[,5])`?

Comment: the 5th and 6th column have the same number of observations. it gives the same result after I changed it to length(temp[,5])

Comment: Do you really mean to start from row 101?  How many rows do you expect in the data frame?

Comment: Yes, I have 243 rows, and I use the first 100 observations to estimate the coefficients. I now want to test those coefficients by using the rest of observations. The code I put here is just one section of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract the data from the `xts` object first

```
library(quantmod) 

xts_object <- getSymbols("000001.SZ", from= '2016-1-1', src="yahoo", auto.assign = F) 
temp <- coredata(xts_object)

for (i in 101:length(temp[,6]))
{ 
  if (   temp[i-1,5]<temp[i,5]  ) 
    print(temp[i,])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I highly agree with your idea. Only the data in the fifth column is the trading volume, the rest columns are stock price data. However the 5th column is very important to me, I can not simple ignore them. I tried to fix it by adding 1 to every value in the fifth column, like: K<- temp[,5]+1. But it still gives me an error. Could you please share some of your opinion on it? I can give you the data I downloaded, if you think it would help.

Comment: Yes, please do!

Comment: I think it would be convenience for you to download it through R, because that's how I download the data in the first place. You just need to run the following code: 
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

temp <- getSymbols("000001.SZ", from= '2016-1-1', src="yahoo", auto.assign = F)

Comment: The problem is that `temp` here is not a data frame, but an `xts` object. When you index it like this, it returns another `xts` object of one value, and the less-than operator doesn't just compare the single values inside these objects as you'd want it to. The solution is to extract the actual data from the `xts` object using the `coredata()` function. See above for the final solution.